# C# парсинг многомерного xml файла

Tags: c#, xml, commerceml

Имею XML файл большой вложенности по протоколу CommerceML
Сам файл достаточно большой поэтому выложу его по ссылке
[XML file](https://dropmefiles.com/d2srL)

Хочу получить из него некоторые поля, вот мой код

```
var import = XDocument.Load("import/import.xml").Descendants("Каталог").Elements("Товары")
             .Elements("Товар")
             .Select(m => new
             {
                 name = m.Elements("Наименоавние")
                     .Select(n => n.Value),


                 atr = m.Elements("Артикул")
                     .Select(a => a.Value),

                 opt = m.Elements("ЗначенияСвойств").Elements("ЗначенияСвойства")
                     .Select(o => new
                     {
                         id = o.Element("Ид").Value,
                         value = o.Element("Значение").Value
                     })
             })
             .ToArray();

         var str = new StreamWriter("models.txt");
         foreach (var im in import)
         {
             str.WriteLine(value: im.name);
             str.WriteLine(im.atr);
             str.WriteLine(im.opt);
             str.WriteLine();
         }
         str.Close();

         Console.WriteLine("done");
```

Однако на выходе получаю не значения элементов, а их типы.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а почему, не хотите использовать сериализацию?

Comment: @Monomax а не покажете пример?

Answer (score 1):

Победил сам себя.

```
var import = XDocument.Load("import/import.xml").Descendants("Каталог").Elements("Товары")
             .Elements("Товар")
             .Select(m => new
             {

                 name = (string) m.Element("Наименование"),

                 atr = (string)m.Element("Артикул"),

                 opt = m.Elements("ЗначенияСвойств").Elements("ЗначенияСвойства")
                     .Select(o => new
                     {
                         id = o.Element("Ид").Value,
                         value = o.Element("Значение").Value
                     }).ToArray()
             });



         var str = new StreamWriter("models.txt");
         foreach (var im in import)
         {
             str.WriteLine(im.name);
             str.WriteLine(im.atr);
             foreach (var ot in im.opt)
             {
                 str.WriteLine(ot.id);
                 str.WriteLine(ot.value);
             }
             str.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
             str.WriteLine();
         }
         str.Close();


         Console.WriteLine("done");
```